# jqGrid change row values

Tags: jqgrid

How can I change data already present in my grid's row with different data on click of a button?
I want to update the values of selected row with new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code could look like

```
var myGrid = $("#list");
var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
myGrid.jqGrid('setRowData',selRowId,newData);
```

where the `newData` in the object of data that contain the new values. The structure of array is in type name:value (for example {firstName:"foo", lastName:"bar"}). You can examine the current data from the row with

```
var oldData = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData',selRowId);
```